# Sum of square of function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, differential-forms, differential

If $f'(x) = g(x)$ and $g'(x) = - f(x)$ for all real $x$ and $f(5) =2 =f'(5)$ then we  have to find $f^2$$(10) + g^2(10)$

I tried but got stuck [image]

Comment: You are just one step away from solving the problem! What is $\int f'(x) f(x) dx$?

Comment: @Karthik but how.to solve that , is there any other method also

Comment: Do you know the change of variables formula for integration?

Comment: Compute the derivative of $h(x)=f(x)^2+g(x)^2$.

Comment: @Karthik no I don't know change of variable fomula

Comment: @koolman Ok. I will post the answer for your benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose 
\begin{eqnarray}
I=\int f'(x) f(x) dx.
\end{eqnarray}

Putting $f(x)=t$, we get $f'(x)~dx=dt$, and thus, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
I=\int t dt=\frac{t^{2}}{2}+c=\frac{(f(x))^{2}}{2}+c,
\end{eqnarray}

where $c$ is a constant of integration. Using this formula, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
0=\int f'(x) f(x) dx+\int g'(x) g(x) dx=\frac{(f(x))^{2}}{2}+\frac{(g(x))^{2}}{2}+c.
\end{eqnarray}

Use $f(5)=2=f'(5)=g(5)$ to solve for $c$. We get $c=-4$. Thus, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(f(x))^{2}}{2}+\frac{(g(x))^{2}}{2}=4~\text{for all}~x.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, $(f(10))^{2}+(g(10))^{2}=8$.

Answer (score 4):

Use Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
f'(x)=g(x)\\
g'(x)=-f(x)\\
f(5)=f'(5)=2
\end{cases}
$$

Take the Laplace transform of both sides:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[f'(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[g(x)\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow s\text{F}(s)-f(0)=\text{G}(s)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[g'(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[-f(x)\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow s\text{G}(s)-g(0)=-\text{F}(s)$$

So, we get that:

1. $$\text{F}(s)=\frac{\text{G}(s)+f(0)}{s}$$
2. $$\text{G}(s)=\frac{g(0)-\text{F}(s)}{s}$$

Now use substitution, to get:

1. $$\text{F}(s)=\frac{sf(0)+g(0)}{1+s^2}$$
2. $$\text{G}(s)=\frac{sg(0)-f(0)}{1+s^2}$$

With inverse Laplace transform:

1. $$f(x)=f(0)\cos(x)+g(0)\sin(x)$$
2. $$g(x)=g(0)\cos(x)-f(0)\sin(x)$$

And notice that we can say that $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ are constants.

Using the initial conditions:

$$f(0)=2(\cos(5)-\sin(5)),g(0)=2(\sin(5)+\cos(5))$$

So, using this gives us:

$$f(10)^2+g(10)^2=8$$